Who is the actress in "the man from the UNCLE" who asks Napoleon "are you ok?"
This actress has only one line in the movie. It happens just after the security guard punches Napoleon. Napoleon is on the floor and the unknown actress goes to him and asks if he is ok. Victoria arrives shortly and coldly brushes the unknown actress away. Who is she? 


You'll help yourself out a lot if you can find an image of her from the film somehow. It's difficult to be sure we have the correct person if we can't see her.

Can you find her picture here? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638355/fullcredits/

She actually looks like director Guy Ritchie's wife - model, Jacqui Ainsley.
Guy and Jacqui

This would likely explain why she's uncredited... 

Yes, I think you are right. Good catch!

I went through the actor list on IMDB, I think this could be Ekaterina Zalitko:
A Showreel: 


IMDB:
http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4417976/
Her Instagram:
https://instagram.com/ekaterinazalitko/
